# how to display next bootstrap tab on button click

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-tabs

I want to display next bootstrap tabs one by one on button click.Right now on button click only the second tab is displayed as i have hard coded it what should be in place of the href="#second" how to get the particular id in the href?When I first click on other tabs instead of  clicking on the first tab which is active then the user must get the error message that ' the user have to click the first tab and then the other tabs' using noty plugin means disable the other tabs except for the first tab on page load .

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){

        $('#changetabbutton').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#mytabs a[href="#second"]').tab('show');
        });

    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul id="mytabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="active">
          <a href="#first" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-home"></i> First tab
          </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#second" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
          <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Second tab
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#third" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Third tab
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#fourth" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Fourth tab
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#fourth" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Fifth tab
          </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade active in cont" id="first">
          <h2>First tab</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade cont" id="second">
          <h2>Second tab</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade cont" id="third">
          <h2>Third tab</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade cont" id="third">
          <h2>Fourth tab</h2>
      </div>
       <div class="tab-pane fade cont" id="third">
          <h2>Fifth tab</h2>
      </div>

    </div>
     <button type="button" id="changetabbutton" class="btn btn-primary ">Set next tab</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want like this http://www.bootply.com/7xfefgP5bf ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    $('#changetabbutton').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var next = $('#mytabs li.active').next()
        next.length?
          next.find('a').click():
          $('#mytabs li a')[0].click();
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){

        $('#changetabbutton').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var next = $('#mytabs li.active').next()
            next.length?
              next.find('a').click():
              $('#mytabs li a')[0].click();
        });

    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul id="mytabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="active">
          <a href="#first" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-home"></i> First tab
          </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#second" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
          <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Second tab
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#third" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Third tab
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#fourth" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Fourth tab
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#fourth" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Fifth tab
          </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade active in cont" id="first">
          <h2>First tab</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade cont" id="second">
          <h2>Second tab</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade cont" id="third">
          <h2>Third tab</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade cont" id="third">
          <h2>Fourth tab</h2>
      </div>
       <div class="tab-pane fade cont" id="third">
          <h2>Fifth tab</h2>
      </div>

    </div>
     <button type="button" id="changetabbutton" class="btn btn-primary ">Set next tab</button>
</div>
```

Comment: try clicking your "Set next tab" button really fast!

Answer (score 5):

By using `$('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a')` selector you can select next tab and make it active. And if next selector not found make the first tab active.

```js
$(function(){

  $('#changetabbutton').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var next_tab = $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a');
    if(next_tab.length>0){
      next_tab.trigger('click');
    }else{
      $('.nav-tabs li:eq(0) a').trigger('click');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul id="mytabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#first" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i> First tab
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#second" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Second tab
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#third" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Third tab
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#fourth" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Fourth tab
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#fourth" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Fifth tab
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade active in cont" id="first">
      <h2>First tab</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade cont" id="second">
      <h2>Second tab</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade cont" id="third">
      <h2>Third tab</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade cont" id="third">
      <h2>Fourth tab</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade cont" id="third">
      <h2>Fifth tab</h2>
    </div>

  </div>
  <button type="button" id="changetabbutton" class="btn btn-primary ">Set next tab</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```js
$('#changetabbutton').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var link = $('#mytabs .active').next().children('a').attr('href');

  $('#mytabs a[href="' + link + '"]').tab('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul id="mytabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#first" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i> First tab
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#second" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Second tab
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#third" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Third tab
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#fourth" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Fourth tab
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#fifth" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Fifth tab
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade active in cont" id="first">
      <h2>First tab</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade cont" id="second">
      <h2>Second tab</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade cont" id="third">
      <h2>Third tab</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade cont" id="fourth">
      <h2>Fourth tab</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade cont" id="fifth">
      <h2>Fifth tab</h2>
    </div>

  </div>
  <button type="button" id="changetabbutton" class="btn btn-primary ">Set next tab</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me but when the user is on the fifth tab and when he clicks on the setnexttab button nothing should happen he should not be redirected o the first tab

Comment: The code does not redirect to the first tab after reaching the last tab. Do you mean that you want to redirect to first tab after click the next btn on the last tab?

Answer (score 0):

use this code in JQUery

```
$('#changetabbutton').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mytabs a[href="#second"]').tab('show');
    })
```

Comment: I have used that only but that is only going into the second tab but when i click on the 'set tab' button which is there in the the second tab it should go into the third tab and same for the other tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Saving the tab number as a variable and just adding to it, or resetting it to 1, depending on which tab they're on seems to work. I renamed the id's of the tabs to numbers to fit this solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){
  
  var tab = 1;
  
        $('#changetabbutton').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
   if(tab>4){
    tab = 1;
   }else{
    tab++;
   }
            $('#mytabs a[href="#'+tab+'"]').tab('show');
        });

    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul id="mytabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li class="active">
          <a href="#1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-home"></i> First tab
          </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
          <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Second tab
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Third tab
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Fourth tab
          </a>
      </li>
      <li>
          <a href="#5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Fifth tab
          </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane fade active in cont" id="1">
          <h2>First tab</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade cont" id="2">
          <h2>Second tab</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade cont" id="3">
          <h2>Third tab</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade cont" id="4">
          <h2>Fourth tab</h2>
      </div>
       <div class="tab-pane fade cont" id="5">
          <h2>Fifth tab</h2>
      </div>

    </div>
     <button type="button" id="changetabbutton" class="btn btn-primary ">Set next tab</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code worked for me

```
$("#buttonNext").click(function(e){
   $('#myTab li:nth-child(2) button').tab('show')
});
```