# How to change active list item in typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have some list items which are treated as Tabs in my UI. I also have a 'next' button under every tab and last tab have a 'finish' button. I need to move to next tab when i clicked on 'Next' button. I am working on an Angular2 project with typescript version 2.3.4. So i need some typescript code to work on button click.
While searching, i got some jquery code like, 
`$('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a')` from [how to display next bootstrap tab on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39451674/how-to-display-next-bootstrap-tab-on-button-click).
I tried it in my button click(.ts file) and it works!. But i am not sure about the using of jquery in my project. Is it possible to get the element(html) in its typescript file? Or is this is the good possible way to do this?
My list is like,

```
<div class="row">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs bg-white">
              <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#BasicInfo">BasicInfo</a></li>
              <li id="idAddInfoTab"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#AdditionalInfo">AdditionalInfo</a></li>
              <li id="idPlayerIdentity" class="active-border"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#PlayerIdentity">PlayerIdentity</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

**page.ts**

```
//declare 3 variables
isT1Active:boolean = true;
isT2Active:boolean = false;
isT3Active:boolean = false;
...
activate(elem){
  //deactivate all first
  this.isT1Active = false;
  this.isT2Active = false;
  this.isT3Active = false;

  switch(elem){
    case 't1':{this.isT1Active = true;break;}
    case 't2':{this.isT2Active = true;break;}
    case 't3':{this.isT3Active = true;break;}
  }
}
```

**page.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs bg-white">
     <li [ngClass]="{'active': isT1Active}" (click)="activate("t1")"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#BasicInfo">BasicInfo</a></li>
     <li  [ngClass]="{'active': isT2Active}" (click)="activate("t2")" id="idAddInfoTab"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#AdditionalInfo">AdditionalInfo</a></li>
     <li  [ngClass]="{'active': isT3Active}" (click)="activate("t3")" id="idPlayerIdentity" class="active-border"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#PlayerIdentity">PlayerIdentity</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And you can do same thing to the `next button`, In assume that each tab will have a next button

Comment: i tried this, but only selected list is changing. I mean,`data-toggle="tab" href="#AdditionalInfo"` this is not getting worked when i click 'next' button in first tab.

Comment: it's not changing the tab or the selected class?

Comment: you need to add `(click)="activate("t1")"` to the next button from tab1

Comment: I added `(click)="activate("t1")"` in next button. But it is just changing the tab(not its contents) as i said in above comment.

Comment: `private OnBasicInfoNextClick() {
        /*TODO: need to find equivalent typescript*/
        $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
    }` .This jquery was working fine. But now i need to remove jquery from my .ts file.

Comment: try to move `(click)="activate("")"` from `li` to `a`

Answer (score 0):

I would stay away from jQuery, but instead learn how to better use Angular to control the view. Basically, you want the `active` class in your template tab to be bound to your component selected model, so that when the selected model is updated, Angular will automatically apply the `active` class to the matching tab.

In your component, define the array that stores the tab info and define a `selectedTab` that refers to the specific tab that should be active:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  tabs = [
    {id:'idBasicInfo', href:'...',label:'BasicInfo'},
    {id:'idAddInfo', href:'...',label:'AdditionalInfo'},
    {id:'idPlayerIdentity',href:'...',label:'PlayerIdentity'}
  ];
  selectedTab = this.tabs[0]; // which is active by default
}
```

Then in your template, use these properties to drive the view:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let t of tabs" [id]="t.id" [class.active]="t===selectedTab">
    <a data-toggle="tab" [href]="t.href" (click)="selectedTab=t"> {t.label}} </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When a tab is clicked, it will be made the `selectedTab` and its `active` class will be set.

Comment: I tried this way also. But it is not changing tab contents even i clicked on tab itself.